# SSL configuration using Certbot

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm encountering some challenges while attempting to create an SSL certificate for my AWS (Amazon Web Services) setup using Certbot. I've followed several tutorials and guides, but I keep running into issues. Here's a breakdown of my problem:

.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM8QW.jpg)

Goal: I want to secure my AWS-hosted website with SSL encryption using Certbot to obtain and manage the SSL certificate.

Issue: Despite following the steps outlined in various tutorials, I'm unable to successfully generate a valid SSL certificate for my AWS instance.

Details:

AWS Setup: I have a web application running on an AWS EC2 instance, and I'm using Route 53 for DNS management.

Certbot Installation: I've installed Certbot on my AWS EC2 instance and ensured that it's up-to-date.

Challenge: When I run the Certbot command to obtain the SSL certificate, I encounter errors or failures at various steps. These errors include challenges with DNS verification, certificate renewal, or configuration issues.

Configuration: I've tried configuring Certbot with both standalone and webroot modes, and I've made sure that my security groups and firewall settings allow inbound traffic on port 80 and 443.

Documentation and Guides: I've consulted the official Certbot documentation, AWS documentation, and various online tutorials, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue

Comment: Why not use AWS Certificate Manager with a load balancer for a free certificate with automatic rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether you can access it through the HTTP protocol, and also check that the server name is correctly configured on the web server configuration (nginx, apache)

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    # Other Nginx configuration... }
```

Instead of Certbot, you could explore using ACM ([AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/resources/?nc=sn&loc=5)) to manage SSL certificates directly within AWS.